# Is it an easy way to implement html like ancher in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want to implment a navigate panel with buttons to control the scrollbar position of a scroll viewer. The button effect will like an ancher in html page. If click one button then the content will scroll to relative position in the scroll viewer. Is it an easy way to implement this?

```
--------------------------------------------
|Button0 |   Button 0 relative content    | |
|Button1 |   ...                          | |
|Button2 |   ...                          |-|
|---------   ...                          |||
|                                         |||  <--the scrollbar
|            ...                          |-|
|            Button 1 relative content    | |
|            ...                          | |
|            ...                          | |
|            Button 2 relative content    | |
---------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky because there is no build in utility function for this (as far as I know).
At the moment I can think of two feasible solutions:

**First Solution:** Calculate the scroll positions for your Content via [UIElement.TransformToVisual Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189872%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
Something like this (not tested, not done any brainwork):

```
private void GotoContent3()
{
    var generaltransform = m_content3.TransformToVisual( m_scrollviewer);
    Point offset = generaltransform.Transform( new Point( 0, 0 ) );
    m_scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset( offset.Y );
}
```

**Second Solution (not recommended):** Use a ListBox to display your Content and call [ListBox.ScrollIntoView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I prefer to choose the first solution, the second solution have to add additional logic to help smooth scroll.

Comment: By the way, there is a method called scrollViewer.ScrollIntoView(Content) works the same as listbox.ScrollIntoView method. But I don't use it, because it doesn't always make the content scroll to the top of view. To complete this requirement have to change the code to Point offset = generaltransform.Transform( new Point( 0, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset ) ); Thanks again!

Comment: @Erxin: If my answer provided the information that lead to your solution please mark it as accepted.